# Remove description from displaying on Woocommerce main shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, action

**I am trying to:**

1. remove the description on the Woocommerce main shop page
2. re-add the description below the products
3. achieve this using child theme's functions.php

However the remove_action queries don't work and the description now displays above and below the products.

**I don't want to rely on css** to hide the duplicate description as I believe it is bad for SEO.

What is the correct action to remove?

**Todo this I've tried:**

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'add_shop_page_description');
function add_shop_page_description(){ 
  if (is_shop() && !property_exists(get_queried_object(), 'slug')){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_product_archive_description', 10 );
 
    $shop_id = woocommerce_get_page_id('shop');
    $content = get_the_content(null, false, $shop_id);
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following in your functions.php in your child theme.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_product_archive_description', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'add_shop_page_description');
function add_shop_page_description(){ 
  if (is_product()){  
    $shop_id = wc_get_page_id('shop'); // replace woocommerce_get_page_id() with wc_get_page_id()
    $content = get_the_content(null, false, $shop_id);
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, why does the remove_action work outside of the function but not inside? Thank you.

Comment: In later action you are trying to remove earlier action.